# String append in for each loop on laravel

Tags: php, string, laravel, append

I'm using a for each loop and fetching the value into the variable `crosslisted_courses` and also appending the next values in the loop into it, but the value does not gets appended!! The variable only stores the last fetched value

Have used `.=` to append the string !!

```
@foreach($fmfacactinss as $fmfacactins_slave)                                                                                                                                              

@if(($fmfacactins_slave->xlist_ctrl_crn == $master_crn) && ($fmfacactins_slave->crn <> $master_crn) ) 
@php  
$crosslisted_courses = '';                                                                                
$slave_crn=$fmfacactins_slave->crn;                                                                                
$crosslisted_courses .= $fmfacactins_slave->crs_subj_cd . ' ' . 
$fmfacactins_slave->crs_nbr . ' ' . $fmfacactins_slave->sect_nbr . ' ';                                                                                
echo($crosslisted_courses);                                                                                
@endphp
@endforeach
```

Comment: Where is your loop? It's maybe not appended because you have `$crosslisted_courses = '';`. Is this statement inside the loop?

Comment: Yes it is inside the loop, if i don't declare the variable , it is giving out  no variable declared error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar to Laravel syntax, but I think you should declare `$crosslisted_courses` before the loop.

```
@php  
$crosslisted_courses = '';
@endphp

@foreach($fmfacactinss as $fmfacactins_slave)

@if(($fmfacactins_slave->xlist_ctrl_crn == $master_crn) && ($fmfacactins_slave->crn <> $master_crn) ) 
@php
$slave_crn=$fmfacactins_slave->crn;
$crosslisted_courses .= $fmfacactins_slave->crs_subj_cd . ' ' . 
    $fmfacactins_slave->crs_nbr . ' ' . $fmfacactins_slave->sect_nbr . ' ';                                                                                
echo($crosslisted_courses);
@endphp

@endforeach
```